# Use Kendo colorpicker with hex input in the Editor for text color using MVC

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using the Kendo `editorFor` to replace an old editor in my MVC application, and need to use a hex editor for the text/background colors. The three options I found are basic, websafe, and null, and none of those let you input hex values in the UI. Is there a way to use the [hex colorpicker](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/colorpicker/rgb-hex) for the text of an `editorFor`?

I do realize that there is an option to give it a list of hex values and it'll make a custom view, but I have likely hundreds of hex values, so it would be much better to be able to paste them in like I could in the old editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With v2023.1.314 to change the predefined ForeColor and BackColor tools of the Editor use a custom tool, add the definition of the ColorPickers and a change event to execute the corresponding Editor's command:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Editor()
        .Name("editor")
        .Value("Some content here")
        .Tools(tools => tools
            .Clear()
            .CustomTemplate(x => x.Name("TextColorTool")
              .Template(
                Html.Kendo().ColorPicker()
                .Name("foreColor")
                .ToolIcon("k-i-foreground-color")
                .Format(ColorPickerFormat.Hex)
                .Events(ev=>ev.Change("function(e){change(e,'foreColor')}"))
                .Formats(new string[] { "rgb", "hex" }).ToHtmlString() +

                Html.Kendo().ColorPicker()
                    .Name("backColor")
                    .ToolIcon("k-i-paint")
                    .Format(ColorPickerFormat.Hex)
                    .Events(ev=>ev.Change("function(e){change(e,'backColor')}"))
                    .Formats(new string[] { "rgb", "hex" })
                .ToHtmlString()
              ))
        )      
)

<script>
  function change(e, commandName) {
    var editor = $("#editor").data("kendoEditor");
    editor.exec(commandName, { value: e.sender.value() });
  }
</script>
```

Here is an [example](https://netcorerepl.telerik.com/cxkxQLkW20EhlUUG46)

Comment: Thank you! Where in the docs is this, I was looking all over but couldn't find it. Also, in the EditorFor cshtml, how do I implement the custom picker on the `ForeColor` and `BackColor` tools?

Comment: That's demonstrated in the Custom Editing for the Grid, [for example](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/html-helpers/data-management/grid/editing/custom). However, it seems I have completely  misunderstood the question. With the latest updates 2023.1.117 and 2023.1.314 there are some breaking changes in the Editor and Toolbar components (check the Breaking Changes section) so currently so passing null for a pallette option does not seem to work anymore. I was able to change the color editors using a custom tool though. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks this worked to get the controls on the toolbar, however its not actually changing the colors of the text. Annoying no errors are thrown, i can see `editor` is found in the js and the exec isn't throwing an error

Comment: Which Kendo version are you using? If it is one prior to 2023.1.314 try `forecolor` and `backcolor` for command names, for example `.Events(ev=>ev.Change("function(e){change(e,'forecolor')}"))`

Comment: As it turns out, I had an error in my code (I didn't have the `{value: ...}` part of the exec call in my js, it was just (`commandName, e.value)`). Of all things on SO, an error from not copy/pasting :)